# Can I avoid redeployment of a project in WebLogic, if I only change JSPs?

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, jrebel, dcevm

I have a project that runs inside the WebLogic server. 80 % of changes I do to the code affect JSP files only (not the class files). Those JSP files contain the frontend logic.

Whenever I change the JSP page, I need to do the following steps to see my changes:

1. `mvn install` inside the source directory.
2. Redeploy the application in WebLogic Admin Console ("Deployments", "Update").

Is it possible to avoid these two steps, if the only thing I change are JSP files (I don't touch Java files therefore, no class files are modified)?

Note that the application in question is set up in WebLogic so that it reads the directory with the class files (`myProject/target`), not a WAR file.

I have no definite information whether or not JRebel supports WebLogic. Its only alternative known to me, [DCEVM](https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm), does not support WebLogic according to the last statement [here](https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm/issues/98).

**Update 1 (02.05.2018 15:23 MSK):** Changing

```
    <wls:resource-reload-check-secs>-1</wls:resource-reload-check-secs>
```

to

```
    <wls:resource-reload-check-secs>1</wls:resource-reload-check-secs>
```

in `myProject/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml` didn't help. When I deploy the application, then make a change to a JSP file, then run `mvn install`, the changes do not take effect.

Comment: JRebel certainly supports WebLogic and reloading JSP-s.

Answer (score 2):

There is  **page-check-seconds** properties in weblogic.xml (beside others). Take a look at ["weblogic.xml"](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WBAPP/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP589)

Comment: Do make sure you do not deploy this setting into *production* though. It will result in the JSPs being recompiled on every request, thus leading to locking of resources on the filesystem and queuing. Only use this in *development*.

Comment: I tried your solution (see update 1), but it didn't work. Suggestions what I could do differently are welcome.

Comment: @DP_ I'm sorry but you add "page-check-seconds" as well? Just make sure you redeploy the webapp. If you still have issue you may want to use console/WLST to get the runtime data (MBean) and enable debug flags. If you happen to know jsp compile path you can also verify the .java/.class file timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If you run in dev mode and not prod wls will redeploy each time a jsp changes at source

Answer (score -1):

No, for several reasons. JSPs have to be **compiled**. They are not simple html pages. They are also cached by the server. You most definitely have to redeploy the project.

Comment: That is not true. With flags like `page-check-seconds` and `resource-reload-check-secs` you can not only deploy new JSPs but also new static files like .js too.